# Move cursor up after deleting a line in VSCode

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

In IntelliJ IDEA there is a setting I quite enjoy: When you delete an empty line, its cursor automatically move to the upper line, like this:

[image]

How can I assign this setting in VSCode ?

Comment: It should be mentioned that what you are doing is actually `SHIFT` + `DELETE` in IntelliJ.

Comment: no, I press Backspace button

Comment: Doesn't backspace do this in VS Code?

Comment: yes, backspace only delete to the top of the line.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `editor.action.deleteLines` to delete the current line by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

However, your cursor will not move up after the line is deleted as you have shown in IntelliJ.  I don't see a built-in option for this feature right now, but you can create your own macro to do it with the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension. It only takes a couple minutes to configure.

1. Install the macros extension.
2. Add the following to your `settings.json` file to create a macro called `deleteLinesUp` that will delete the line and then move the cursor up.

   ```
   "macros": {
       "deleteLinesUp": [
           "editor.action.deleteLines",
           "cursorUp"
       ]
   },
   ```
3. Open your `keybindings.json` file and add the following to override <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> so it calls `deleteLinesUp` instead of `deleteLines`.

   ```
   {
       "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
       "command": "macros.deleteLinesUp"
   }
   ```

Now it will behave as you desire. Also, you can bind this macro to whatever key combination you want.

Comment: If I want to implement this feature(delete line and move cursor up) in my developing vscode extension, how to do it ?

Answer (score 11):

You want to install the [Hungry Delete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jasonlhy.hungry-delete) extension.

It changes the behavior of the backspace. When you hit backspace in a line that has none other than white space, it erases the whole line and moves the cursor up, which is the same behavior of JetBrains' editors, demonstrated in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts

search for "Delete All Left" and "Delete All Right"

and add your keys, I prefer to use Ctrl+Shift+Backspace and Ctrl+Shift+End